# Как нажать на кнопку на сайте из C#?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Есть сайт с кнопкой. Как мне программно на нее нажать?

Comment: почему именно C#? Манипуляции на клиенте - это чаще всего JasvaScript

Comment: @dyuranna, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее простой способ:
создаем webBrowser, далее:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("site");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");
```

id можно взять, скажем, если нажать пкм по элементу в хроме и далее inspect element. В выделенной строке найти id="".

Comment: Спасибо, помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button").InvokeMember("click");
```

Или, если эта кнопка - не исключительно кнопка веб-интерфейса, а по клику на неё происходит http-запрос, то можно явно формировать такой запрос и отправлять его из C# кода, только нужно знать url и данные.